# Placing a component containing a formGroup in a formGroup (data-driven from Angular2)

Tags: forms, angular, data-driven, reactive

I've got 2 components:

- the first component is a formGroup for user details
- the second component is should be nested as an address formGroup, user formGroup

the selectors are:

```
 - <ts-user></ts-user>
 - <ts-address></ts-address>
```

Since a user can have more than one address and I would like to make the address component containing the form reusable. I'd like to know how to nest the address component in the user's component. Like this:

```
<ts-user>
 <ts-address></ts-address>
</ts-user>
```

Clearly, placing the address selector in the user selector does not create any error, but I'd like to know how to make validation work on both.

Any full/pseudo-code or any tutorial to "enlight" me would be of great help.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Comment: yep, I've already checked that link. It deals with formGroup arrays defined in the same controller. It's not related to my situation.

Comment: You would have to make them part of the same form that is defined within the parent component and handle validation there. That's how I'm doing it, at least.

Comment: @user3608792 Your suggestion worked, thanks. For some mystical reason I wasn't  considering that "Input" binding passed a reference. This opens all the gates.